# When pagination is activate in p:dataTable?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.2

How can I know when the user is pushing one of the  pagination button in p:dataTable ?

Thanks

Comment: I'd start determining the request parameters.

Comment: Uhm, just use browser's builtin developer toolset. Once you find one key parameter which indicates that a pagination request is performed, then just intercept on that in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an ajax behaviour when user changes the page, you can use the following code:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.collection}" var="obj" >
      <p:ajax event="page" update="componentsToUpdateOnPage" listener="#{bean.pageListener}" />
      <p:column>
         .. etc..
</p:dataTable>
```

If you are using a lazy loading data table, you have to override the load() method of LazyDataModel. that method is executed on page load, when page changes and also when you sort or filter the datatable.